# Ubuntu server 16.04 - mysql , The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

necesito ayuda, estoy montando un `servidor web` con `ubuntu server 16.04`  , `apache`, `mysql` y `php` , y estoy intentando importar datos de un archivo de texto a `mysql` y me sale el siguiente mensaje :

> The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement: LOAD DATA INFILE , por favor ayudenme con este problema

Answer (score 1):

tienes dos opciones:

1. Mover el el fichero al directorio especificado por `secure-file-priv`
2. Desactivar `secure-file-priv`Esto lo haras modificando el valor en el fichero my.cnf de tu servidor. Despues hacer un restart de mysql.

La ubicación del mysqld.cnf creo que es la valida para Ubunut Xenial, pero otras distros puede variar como /etc/my.cnf

```
sudo EDITOR /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
secure-file-priv = ""
```

[Mysql :: 6.1.4 Server System Variables :: sysvar secure file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv)